# CakePhp sorting the output of $this->Form->input

Tags: php, cakephp

I have looked at all stackoverflow examples and the CakePhp documentation.
But apparently I'm just not smart enough...

My code is:

```
echo $this->Form->input('clan_id', array('label' => 'Clan', 'value' => $this->data['User']['clanId'], 'order' => array('clan_id' => 'asc')));
```

It works, but the output is not in order:

```
<option value="1">clan5</option>
<option value="2">clan2</option>
<option value="3">clan21</option>
<option value="4">clan15</option>
<option value="5">clan8</option>
...
```

What I want is off course:

```
<option value="1">clan2</option>
<option value="2">clan5</option>
<option value="3">clan8</option>
<option value="4">clan15</option>
<option value="5">clan21</option>
...
```

I've tried multiple things:
- Changing the order statement in so many ways I don't remember them all
- Tried it like [the documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html) said

I found out that the input helper has no order option [here](http://api.cakephp.org/1.3/class-FormHelper.html#_input)
So I'm guessing I need to work with `Set::sort` or there is something wrong with my code.
(Or I'm just not smart enough)
Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction?

My SQL table structure:

```
1 id
2 leaderId
3 name
4 tag
5 website
6 logo
7 game_id
8 mem_id
9 game_name
10 preference
```

The ID in my user table I use is `clanId`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Controller`:

```
$this->set('clans', $this->Clan->find('list', array('order' => array('name' => 'asc)));
```

`View`:

```
echo $this->Form->input('clan_id', array('label' => 'Clan', 'options' => $clans, 'value' => $this->data['User']['clan_id']));
```

Comment: Warning (2): ksort() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given

Comment: I don't understand where I'm supposed to add the code for the controller, could u explain please?

Comment: In the code you have, cake knows to do the joins and select the correct clan. In my code, you are giving it the list of clans already sorted

Comment: you mean this line: $this->data['User']['clanId'] = $this->data['User']['clan_id']; ?

Comment: `'value' => $this->data['User']['clan_id'])` can be skipped. Cake will fill it automatically

Comment: Notice (8): Undefined index: clan_id

Comment: please paste your table structure. It's hard to guess what your fields are called.

Comment: where is the clan_id then?

Comment: The ID in my user table I use is clanId (sorry forgot that one)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48079/discussion-between-cornelb-and-gelleby)

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse, `FormHelper::input` dosen't have order option.
Use [`Hash::sort`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/hash.html#Hash%3a%3asort) instead of `Set::sort`, if You want sort in view, but better is sorting in controller before set variable to view or use [`$order`](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-Model.html#%24order) varible in model

Comment: Could u provide some examples please? Because I can't seam to find any documentation of working examples.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort the input of dropdown you have to do it from controller. let's say you want to sort user list.

```
public function user_list(){
    $users = $this->User->find('list');
    asort($users);
    $this->set('users', $users);
}
```

1. remove order array from first line input
2. $this->data['User']['clanId'] should be $this->data['User']['clan_id']

you have to assign order into your controller . if you what to sort by each field you have to use `$this->Paginator->sort('clan_id');`